# Select a random single record in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Using ASP.Net MVC3 with C#

How would I go about selecting a single random record from my database?

This is the code I have now

```
CJAd cjad = db.CJAds.Single(c => c.category_id == 1 && c.ad_active == true);
```

Comment: And you like the code you have now, because?..

Comment: You don't need to do `&& c.ad_active == true`, just `&& c.ad_active` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var selection = db.CJAds.Where(c => c.category_id == 1 && c.ad_active);
CJAd cjad = selection
    .OrderBy(c => c.id)
    .Skip(new Random().Next(selection.Count()))
    .First();
```

Comment: This looks good and doesn't error in Visual Studio but throws this error System.NotSupportedException: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: You didn't state which framework you are using. But in this case add some sorting (OrderBy()) before the skip. I can help you here as I do not know your table.

Answer (score 0):

Im on a mobile device so can't check. This should work.

```
CJAd cjad = db.CJADs.Where(c => c.category_id == 1 && c.ad_active).OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think this can't be evaluated on the database and will lead to a full table loading and in memory ordering.